# iterate over vector of unrodered set

Tags: c++, vector

I'm still learning c++ and do not understand one thing that I encountered today.

I see that an adjacency_list_ if defined by

> `std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > bla::blaa::adjacency_list_`

I believe that it is an vector of unordered set.

I want to know:

1. What is this data-structure, vector of unordered set?
2. How can I traverse it to get the adjacency list, please provide a general MWE for traversal of such data-structures?

Thanks in advance for teaching me this new thing.

A minimum (not) working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<unordered_set<int> > my_sets;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        my_sets[i].insert(i*2);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<my_sets.size();i++)
    {
          for(unordered_set<int> :: iterator it = my_sets[i].begin(); it != my_sets[i].end();++it)
        {
           cout << *it;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list ?

Comment: Here's another https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-adjacency-list-algorithm

Comment: @OlafDietsche: tx, but I know what adjacency lists are. My problem are related to iterating over such an data-structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code, your vector is empty, yet you're trying to access indices from 0 to 4. you should set the size of the vector first before iterating. Also you can use range based for loop to avoid writing alot of [boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code).

This code is correct and I think it does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<unordered_set<int>> my_sets(5);
    //                                ^^^
    // number 5 here initializes the vector with the size of 5 

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        my_sets[i].insert(i*2);

    for (auto &my_set : my_sets)
        for (auto num : my_set)
            cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
02468
```

Answer (score 0):

An [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

> is a collection of unordered lists. Each list describes the set of neighbors.

Translating into C++:

```
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > adjlist;
```

The collection (`vector`) of a set of neighbours (`unordered_set`).

---

Traversing depends on what you want to achieve.

If it is just visiting each node, this can be as simple as

```
for (int node = 0; node < adjlist.size(); ++node) {
    // do something with node
}
```

or

```
for (auto &neighbours : adjlist) {
    // do something with each node's neighbours
}
```

---

If you want to navigate from one node to another node, you must look at the neighbours of a node

```
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int> > adjlist = {{2, 5}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3}, {0}};

for (int i = 0; i < adjlist.size(); ++i) {
    auto &neighbours = adjlist[i];
    for (auto n : neighbours) {
        std::cout << i << "->" << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

Since each neighbour points back to each other, this poses the problem of loops and keeping track of already visited nodes.